# Why Doesn't 'DefaultAxesMarkerOrder' Work?

Tags: matlab, plot, formatting, matlab-figure, markers

I have a plot with >7 sets of data.

After the default colours are all used once (i.e. with the first 7 sets of data) I then want the marker style to change and for this to repeat every time all 7 colours have been used for each marker.

I have successfully changed the line style in this manner using:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesLinestyleOrder', '-|--|-.');
```

However changing this to:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesMarkerOrder', '.|+|^|s');
```

Returns the error:

```
Error using set
Invalid property found.
Object Name: axes
Property Name: 'MarkerOrder'.
```

I am unsure as to why substituting `'Marker'` does not work. Potentially because plots by default do not have markers? Though when I try adding:

```
plot(nbead,x,'.')
```

The problem is not solved.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not have a default marker order. Instead, you can specify the marker order *within* the line style specification like this:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesLinestyleOrder', '-o|--^|-.');
```

The cycle that MATLAB uses is locked to the color order as well, so to see other symbols you might change the color order to be shorter:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0; 0 1 0]);
```

Then you could run the following code to show how things change:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0; 0 1 0]);
set(0, 'DefaultAxesLinestyleOrder', '-o|--^|-.');

n = 15;
data = (diag(1:n) * ones(n))';

figure;
hold all
plot(data)
```

For the following output:

[image: Example Image]

You can refer to the Matlab [axes documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) for a bit more info on axes properties.